# SOAP Request tags are getting appended with - and this is causing xml load failure

Tags: xml, soapui

I have SOAP request generated as out from SQL developer as a result of few stored procedures execution.

Recently I am facing challenge when I am trying to execute the request through SOAP

I am getting below error

[SOAP Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIL4Z.png)

I am able to fix this issue by removing hyphen(-) in the below node

`-<soapenv:Envelope xmlns`

Is there a means to remove hyphen this through code rather than manual intervention and save the xml again?

Earlier there was not encoding on the file currently encoding is applied

Earlier the prolog is

`<?xml version="1.0"?>`

currently the prolog is
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Attached is the full XML document any suggestions and approach to overcome this are most welcome.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns="http://www.sterlingcommerce.com/mesa">
    <soapenv:Header> </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <AGY_WS_ZBRA_IB>
            <HeaderMessage>
                <SenderCode> AGILITY_SG1 </SenderCode>
                <ReceiverCode> ZEBRA </ReceiverCode>
                <TransactionCode> SRA </TransactionCode>
                <UniqueMessageIdentifier> 1212kjdfkd121 </UniqueMessageIdentifier>
                <SentTimestamp> 2013-07-17T16:44:49.365-05:00 </SentTimestamp>
                <FileType> XML </FileType>
                <EDIStandard> 888 </EDIStandard>
                <ResponseLevel> BackendSystemLoadConfirmation </ResponseLevel>
            </HeaderMessage>
            <Body>
                <InputParameters
                    xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/db/sp/Set3PLStockReceiptDetails">
                    <P_IN_RCV_DET>
                        <P_IN_RCV_DET_ITEM>
                            <ORG_SYSTEM_ID_3PL> AGILITY_SG1 </ORG_SYSTEM_ID_3PL>
                            <TRANSACTION_TYPE> PO RECEIPT </TRANSACTION_TYPE>
                            <DOCUMENT_NUMBER> 711042153 </DOCUMENT_NUMBER>
                            <LINE_DETAILS>
                                <LINE_DETAILS_ITEM>
                                    <TRANSACTION_DATE> 2018-08-02T18:12:40.000+08:00 </TRANSACTION_DATE>
                                    <UOM> Roll </UOM>
                                    <INVENTORY_ITEM_ID> 92785 </INVENTORY_ITEM_ID>
                                    <PO_SHIPMENT_NUM> 1 </PO_SHIPMENT_NUM>
                                    <LINE_NUMBER> 1 </LINE_NUMBER>
                                    <ITEM_NUMBER> K2300BK11030 </ITEM_NUMBER>
                                    <QUANTITY> 2 </QUANTITY>
                                    <RECEIPT_DATE> 2018-08-02T18:12:40.000+08:00 </RECEIPT_DATE>
                                    <TO_3PL_LOCATOR_STATUS> ACTIVE </TO_3PL_LOCATOR_STATUS>
                                    <SERIAL_DETAILS> </SERIAL_DETAILS>
                                </LINE_DETAILS_ITEM>
                            </LINE_DETAILS>
                        </P_IN_RCV_DET_ITEM>
                    </P_IN_RCV_DET>
                </InputParameters>
            </Body>
        </AGY_WS_ZBRA_IB>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: It's better to post your code/XML as text rather than as images. It helps others reproduce your issue.

Comment: Craig I have added full code for your reference.You can put it in SOAP and see it

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using a browser, probably IE, to view your XML request and save it. IE, in particular, will capture the XML expansion/collapse hyphen when you do this. Use a simple text editor instead.